# argo-server pod replicas failing to authenticate with postgres instance causing `CrashLoopBackOff` pod status. Non-replica works fine

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, bitnami, argo-workflows

I am running an EKS cluster and installed argo-workflows via the [bitnami helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/argo-workflows) on a 3 node cluster (nodes running across different AZs).

When running with all the defaults from [values.yml](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/argo-workflows/values.yaml) everything works perfectly fine. But when I increased the [`server.replicaCount`](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/argo-workflows/values.yaml#L85) from 1 to 3 in the `values.yml` to increase the argo-server replicas, the 2 additional replicas keep crashing with `CrashLoopBackOff` status.

Running `kubectl logs` for the pods that are crashing I can see that they are failing to authenticate with the postgres container. Here is the output of the logs:

```
time="2022-01-05T03:50:16.921Z" level=info msg="not enabling pprof debug endpoints"
time="2022-01-05T03:50:16.924Z" level=info authModes="[client]" baseHRef=/ managedNamespace= namespace=argo secure=false
time="2022-01-05T03:50:16.924Z" level=warning msg="You are running in insecure mode. Learn how to enable transport layer security: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/tls/"
time="2022-01-05T03:50:16.924Z" level=info msg="config map" name=argo-workflows-controller
time="2022-01-05T03:50:16.924Z" level=info msg="SSO disabled"
time="2022-01-05T03:50:16.956Z" level=info msg="Starting Argo Server" instanceID= version=v3.2.6
time="2022-01-05T03:50:16.956Z" level=info msg="Creating DB session"
time="2022-01-05T03:50:16.980Z" level=fatal msg="pq: password authentication failed for user \"postgres\""
```

Any ideas why the replicas would fail to authenticate with the postgres container? The non-replica container does not have this problem and connects just fine. I also tried manually setting a password by overriding the [`postgresql.postgresqlPassword`](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/argo-workflows/values.yaml#L1109) value in `values.yml` but I get the same result. Pretty new to k8s so not exactly sure how to better troubleshoot this properly beyond this point.

Also realized as I was typing this the replica controller is experiencing the same behavior. Here are the logs for the failing controller:

```
time="2022-01-05T21:59:00Z" level=info msg="index config" indexWorkflowSemaphoreKeys=true
time="2022-01-05T21:59:00Z" level=info msg="cron config" cronSyncPeriod=10s
time="2022-01-05T21:59:00.994Z" level=info msg="not enabling pprof debug endpoints"
time="2022-01-05T21:59:00.996Z" level=info msg="config map" name=argo-workflows-controller
time="2022-01-05T21:59:01.027Z" level=info msg="Get configmaps 200"
time="2022-01-05T21:59:01.038Z" level=info msg="Configuration:\nartifactRepository: {}\ncontainerRuntimeExecutor: k8sapi\nexecutor:\n  name: \"\"\n  resources: {}\ninitialDelay: 0s\nmetricsConfig: {}\nnodeEvents: {}\npersistence:\n  connectionPool:\n    maxIdleConns: 100\n  postgresql:\n    database: bn_argo_workflows\n    host: argo-workflows-postgresql\n    passwordSecret:\n      key: postgresql-password\n      name: argo-workflows-postgresql\n    port: 5432\n    tableName: argo_workflows\n    userNameSecret:\n      key: username\n      name: argo-workflows-controller-database\npodSpecLogStrategy: {}\ntelemetryConfig: {}\n"
time="2022-01-05T21:59:01.038Z" level=info msg="Persistence configuration enabled"
time="2022-01-05T21:59:01.038Z" level=info msg="Creating DB session"
time="2022-01-05T21:59:01.044Z" level=info msg="Get secrets 200"
time="2022-01-05T21:59:01.049Z" level=info msg="Get secrets 200"
time="2022-01-05T21:59:01.054Z" level=fatal msg="Failed to update config: pq: password authentication failed for user \"postgres\""
```

Comment: what is Kubernetes version you're using?

Comment: @Bazhikov Using version 1.21

Comment: hi! sorry for late answer. I've found many issues in GitHub regarding increasing replicaCount for `bitnami` charts, but I can't understand how to reproduce your issue with that strange error with the `postgres` user auth. Could you please provide me the command on how you upgraded the replicaCount?

Comment: I don't know if this works for you with your specific error, but there is a workaround with increasing `replicaCount` from `1` to `2`, and then from `2` to `3`. At least you can try and I recommend to open new issue under bitnami charts: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced issue on GKE and I can't see any error with user `\"postgres\"`. The steps taken:

- [Steps from README](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/argo-workflows) to install
- creating values.yaml locally
- `$ helm upgrade my-release bitnami/argo-workflows -f values.yaml --set server.replicaCount=3`
- kubectl get pods

And I can see that all 3 replicas are running and has no any error:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-release-argo-workflows-controller-f5d748797-pkv99   1/1     Running   0          23m
my-release-argo-workflows-server-669c54dddb-l5c9b      1/1     Running   0          23m
my-release-argo-workflows-server-669c54dddb-nqvn2      1/1     Running   0          2m16s
my-release-argo-workflows-server-669c54dddb-w6ftl      1/1     Running   0          2m16s
my-release-postgresql-0                                1/1     Running   0          31m
```

If you are still facing this issue, please [open new Issue request in GitHub](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues) under bitnami charts or update your case with more details here to reproduce.